# Why are high frequency signals not disturbed by stray fields?

Tags: emc, high-frequency, inductive

I am trying to design an inductive position sensor based on a high-frequency signal.

It is mentioned that using high-frequency signals gives immunity towards stray magnetic fields.

Could anyone explain the theory behind this?

Why are the high-frequency signals immune to EMI?

Answer (score 1):

> why the high-frequency signals are immune to EMI?

Not quite. Stray magnetic fields usually means things are more like magnets and coils in the nearby vicinity which are typically much lower frequency than your typical EMI.

It is not that inductive sensors operating at higher frequencies are somehow immune to being influenced by stray magnetic fields as it much as it is that stray magnetic fields are usually of much lower frequency and can therefore be distinguished from your signal of interest. Though I suppose technically it could also be that inductive sensors operating at higher frequencies are able to utilize much smaller inductances so lower frequency stray magnetic fields have to be that much, much stronger in strength (or faster, but that would make them high frequency magnetic fields which stray magnetic fields usually aren't) to induce the same effect on the signal.

Answer (score 1):

An inductive proximity switch comprises a high frequency oscillator, Schmitt trigger and output switching circuit.

The high frequency oscillator tank circuit coil is wound in one half of a ferrite pot core. The exposed end of this coil is the sensing face.

Sensing takes place when a metallic object enters the electromagnetic field emanating from the sensor face. An increase or decrease in inductance of the tank coil, caused by a magnetic or a non-magnetic object respectively, results in a decrease or increase in the frequency of oscillation or stoppage of oscillation itself. Eddy current losses also change the power consumed by the oscillator. The change in oscillator current is sensed by the Schmitt trigger and output as a digital signal.

Higher the frequency, smaller would be the inductance of the coil and the diameter of the pot core and vice versa.

It follows that, higher the frequency, smaller the emanating magnetic field and as a result smaller its sensing distance and vice versa.

Ultimately, smaller the sensing distance, smaller the diameter of the proximity switch and vice versa.

Interference with the functioning of a proximity switch would be more from other nearby proximity switches than from other sources.

Proximity switches with a higher frequency of oscillation can work interference-free at closer distances between them than those with a lower frequency of oscillation.